# Cannot find files for `calcurse` calendar application installed with homebrew : not where documentation says they are

Tags: homebrew, calendar, ical, reminders, open-source

I just installed `calcurse`, an calendar open source solution (which looks great!). I installed version calcurse version 4.7.1 via `homebrew`  (`brew install calcurse`)

I cannot find where the `todo` and `apts` files are located, despite to what is written in the [documentation](https://www.calcurse.org/support/) which says that they are there:

```
$HOME/.calcurse/
          |___apts
          |___conf
          |___hooks/
          |___keys
          |___notes/
          |___todo
```

On my machine, however they are no such structure. Similar files have been installed there:

```
$HOME/.config/calcurse/
                ├── conf
                ├── hooks/
                └── keys
```

There are 2 main differences with respect to the documentation:

- There is no `$HOME/.calcurse/$ directory`
- In `$HOME/.config/calcurse/`: the files `conf` and `keys` are present but `todo` and `apts` are absent (at least not there)

The other location where `brew` installed things is in `/usr/local/Cellar/calcurse/4.7.1`. But there I could not find the files neither

Those files probably exist somewhere because, I imported several time appointments from a `.ics` file and I have (several) duplicates of those appointments. I searched for similar problems but didn't find any

How can I locate those files (`todo` and `apts`)?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I finally the found the location of those 3 missing items (`apts`, `notes/`, `todo`), which are in another location as the three first items (`conf`, `hooks/` `keys`):

```
$HOME/.local/share/calcurse
                     ├── apts
                     ├── notes/
                     └── todo
```

**Edit**
I also tried to install it via a straight compile of the source which resulted in exactly the same outcome:

I uninstalled the app with `brew uninstal calcurse`, removed manually `$HOME/.config/calcurse/` and `$HOME/.local/share/calcurse` downloaded the source `calcurse-4.7.1.tar.gz` from [here](https://www.calcurse.org/downloads/) and installed with

```
$ tar -xzf calcurse-4.7.1.tar.gz
$ cd calcurse-4.7.1
$ ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

and got exactly installed files location. So, on my machine: whether I used `homebrew` or plain source, the location of the file does not correspond to the location in the documentation.

To sum up, here are the paths of the 6 items

```
$HOME/.config/calcurse/
                ├── conf
                ├── hooks/
                └── keys
$HOME/.local/share/calcurse
                     ├── apts
                     ├── notes/
                     └── todo
```

Comment: Well that looks like a bug in calcurse then the documentation should be correct. talk to the maintainers. The change in files looks like they changed the config to a standard default XDG directory structure but forgot to change the documentation

Comment: How is that "installing the port"?

Comment: I meant installing via a MacPort. I edited the answer @MarcWilson

Comment: That's not installing from MacPorts.  That's installing from source.

Comment: @mmmmmm Yeah, there's a delta involved somewhere.  The tarball doesn't seem to include a changelog, but there's a script in it named `calcurse-upgrade` that tries to migrate from the old structure to the new structure.  Really weird that they'd do that, it made MUCH more sense all under one folder.  The XDG spec does really suck.

Comment: XDG setup allows you to put config under version control. But yes the is not Macports but just source code. This answer needs editing

Comment: ALso note that none of these datafiles are created by the install or package manager as Macports and the source code version install via sudo install and so cannot write to the users home directory as the install does not know who the user is. Thus the files are eiuther manually created or created when the program first runs.

Answer (score 0):

They are in `$HOME/.calcurse`, where the man page (and the [documentation](https://www.calcurse.org/support/) freely available from the calcurse home page) says they are.

```
FILES
   The following structure is created by default in your home directory the first time calcurse is run
   without any options:
       
       $HOME/.calcurse/
                 |___apts
                 |___conf
                 |___hooks/
                 |___keys
                 |___notes/
                 |___todo
```

(edit)
I see that Homebrew has broken the application for no good reason... they seem to do that a lot.  For the Homebrew build, the files are under `$HOME/.local/share/calcurse` rather than where they're supposed to be.

```
$ ls -l .local/share/calcurse
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 mwilson  staff   0 Jul 10 11:47 apts
drwx------  2 mwilson  staff  64 Jul 10 11:47 notes
-rw-r--r--  1 mwilson  staff   0 Jul 10 11:47 todo
```

Comment: I read the documentation before writing the question @MarcWilson: On my machine, those files are not in the location where the documentation says they are + the 2 files of interests (`apts` and `todo`) cannot be found at all. Did you try to install the software with `brew install calcurse`? And if yes where are all those files located on your machine?

Comment: No, I would never install Homebrew on a system I cared about.  I spun up a Catalina VM temporarily so I could see what their packaging did.

Comment: Ok. I tend to use homebrew as the package manager for Mac to avoid duplicate / dependencies problem as I encountered such problems in the past when no using homebrew. If you install the application how did you do it without homebrew @MarcWilson?

Comment: @ecjb I read the documentation, then installed it with MacPorts as that was listed here https://www.calcurse.org/downloads/ as an installation method.  I didn't expect that Homebrew would ignore the official documentation.

Comment: Did you install it with MacPorts @MarcWilson? And if yes where were those files installed on your machine? Because I just uninstall the brew version and installed it with MacPorts: The files were installed in the same location as before (which still did not correspond to what was said in the documentation)

Comment: @ecjb Yes, I did.  It does not create anything in `~/.local` and creates `~/.calcurse` if it's not already there.